# svg : nomber of pixel of a character

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am using d3js to create circles inside an svg.  In each circle I want to put some text (a letter to be specific). 
My question is : How to make the center of the text matching the center of the circle ? 
My example is with the word "memo" : the length in pixel of the "m" is bigger than the "e" : so if I position the "e" correctly, the "m" won't be exactly in the middle :(

Here is the code I have :
d[0]    contains the letter
eval_r gives the formula to calculate the circle's radius 
eval_x gives the formula to calculate the x position of the radius's center
eval_y gives the formula to calculate the y position of the radius's center

```
g_.append("text")
    .text   (         function(d,i) { return d[0] ; })
    .attr   ("dx"   , function(d,i) { return x( eval(eval_x) ) + (1/3 * eval(eval_r)) ;}) 
    .attr   ("dy"   , function(d,i) { return y( eval(eval_y) ) - (1/4 * eval(eval_r)) ;})   
    .attr   ("fill" , "white");
```

So I tried empirically to determine 1/3 and 1/4 as being good matches for centering any letters, but as I said, it is not perfect. I would like to determine the length in pixel of an "m" and a "e" (or any letter) to adjust the formula calculating the x so that I can center perfectly the letters inside the circle.

Thks :)

Comment: text-anchor: middle; is all you need isn't it?

Comment: maybe, I will try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me thanks to  Robert :

```
 g_.append("text")
    .text   (         function(d,i) { return d[0] ; })
    .attr   ("text-anchor" , "middle")
    .attr   ("dx"   , function(d,i) { return x( eval(eval_x) ) + (1/2 * eval(eval_r)) ;}) 
    .attr   ("dy"   , function(d,i) { return y( eval(eval_y) ) - (0 * eval(eval_r)) ;})   
    .attr   ("fill" , "white");
```